# How can I add a column that compares values with a second list?

Tags: python

until now I only used excel so I'm new to python, I wanted to know how to do the following operation in python. Thank you very much.

```py
mydata = [['e', 'cat'], 
          ['a', 'dog'], 
          ['i', 'bird'], 
          ['o', 'frog']]

lst = [['a', '1'],
       ['e', '2'],
       ['i', '3'],
       ['o', '4'],
       ['u', '5']]
```

I would like something like that

```py
mydata_1 = [['e', 'cat','2'], 
            ['a', 'dog','1'], 
            ['i', 'bird','3'], 
            ['o', 'frog','4']]
```

Comment: Are you sure this is how your data looks like? it would make much more sense if you have  list of dictionaries. Instead you have a list of sets in one variable and a list of lists in the other

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki I would like to point out that mydata does not contain a list of dictionaries, it contains a list of sets.

Comment: I suggest you use pandas. This would be a `join` operation.

Comment: I just checked the difference between a list and a list of dictionaries and I just changed it, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use a library such as pandas, the following python code produces your desired result:

```py
lst_lookup = dict(lst)
mydata = [[e1, e2, lst_lookup[e1]] for e1, e2 in mydata]
```

I am using what is called a dictionary in the first line.
In the second line I use a list comprehension. You can find more on both here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use "pandas" to create some dataframes for your dataset. In the next step, there are many functions for merging these dataframes. Get help from the link below:

[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-column-from-another-dataframe-in-pandas/#:%7E:text=After%20extraction%2C%20the%20column%20needs,dataframe%20using%20join()%20function.&text=This%20function%20needs%20to%20be,to%20it%20as%20the%20argument.)

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas would be the best solution as suggested, but here it goes with python `for loop` to compare values and appending other value to a new list if corresponding value are equals.

```
mydata = [['e', 'cat'],
          ['a', 'dog'],
          ['i', 'bird'],
          ['o', 'frog']]

lst = [['a', '1'],
       ['e', '2'],
       ['i', '3'],
       ['o', '4'],
       ['u', '5']]

mydata_1 = []

for a in mydata:
    for b in lst:
        if a[0] == b[0]:
            mydata_1.append(a)
            a.append(b[1])
            # print(mydata_1) 

        # [['e', 'cat', '2']]
        # [['e', 'cat', '2'], ['a', 'dog', '1']]
        # [['e', 'cat', '2'], ['a', 'dog', '1'], ['i', 'bird', '3']]
        # [['e', 'cat', '2'], ['a', 'dog', '1'], ['i', 'bird', '3'], ['o', 'frog', '4']]

print(mydata_1)

# [['e', 'cat', '2'], ['a', 'dog', '1'], ['i', 'bird', '3'], ['o', 'frog', '4']]
```